# Stack list elements which are of the same type based on a specific property

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I try (using LINQ) to stack a list of elements which are of the same type and then increment an anonymous property..

```
ElementA
ElementA
ElementB
ElementB
ElementB
ElementC
```

become an anonymous object which expose the element and the quantity..

```
ElementA (Property Qty = 2)
ElementB (Property Qty = 3)
ElementC (Property Qty = 1)
```

Is there any elegant way to do this with LINQ ?

Comment: Is there a way to return a second list of element (anonymously) based on a GroupBy ? Do you have any example using a GroupBy ?

Comment: There are some more examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is at all efficient, but definitely possible.  Something along the lines of

```
var totals = from e in <element list>
             group e by e.<property> into g
             select new {
                Property = g.Key,
                Count = g.Count()
             }
```

will get you a count of the properties.

In this case `g` is of type [`IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which inherits from `IEnumerable<T>` so it can do anything `IEnumerable<T>` can do.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know we could use Count for this. That what was missing. I tried many combinaison using Sum.. but i couldn't get anything with it.